# How to get a List<TypeOf> objects, from this XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I cannot understand this code.

```
        XDocument loaded = XDocument.Load(PATH);
        var devices = new List<Device>(loaded.Descendants("Device").Select(e => new Device
        {
            UserName = "xxx",
            Domain = e.Element("domain").Value,
            FQDN = e.Element("fqdn").Value,
            Password = e.Element("password").Value,

        }));
```

How does it add these elements, and get the list of devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code use LINQ to read the XML and create a list of Device objects with the info of the XML.

Filling the field like this:

- UserName = "xxx" always the UserName property have the same value xxx
- Domain = the value of domain element in the xml
- FQDN = the value of fqdn element in the XML
- Password = the value of password element in the xml

your XML is like this:

```
<Devices>
  <Device>
    <domain>domainValue</domain>
    <fqdn>fqdnValue</fqdn>
    <password>passwordValue</password>
  </Device>
</Devices>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    XDocument loaded = XDocument.Load(PATH);
      // devices = List of device
    var devices = new List<Device>
      //look up for every Device in xml file
    (loaded.Descendants("Device")
      //create new Device object
    .Select(e => new Device
    {
          //and fill it with found element's values
        UserName = "xxx",
        Domain = e.Element("domain").Value,
        FQDN = e.Element("fqdn").Value,
        Password = e.Element("password").Value,

    }));
```